# Проверка переменной на существование и пустоту?

Tags: javascript

Как в Js проверить переменную на пустоту и существование, допустим:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var str = path.split("/");
```

Будет ли нормальной проверка:

```
if(str[2]){
}
```

Comment: а почему явно не проверить нужную длину массива для начала?

    if (str.length > 2 && str[2]) {
    
    }

Comment: @KoVadim, я делаю только проверку на длину, ведь итак понятно, что если длина больше, то там что-то будет

Comment: Возможно недопонимание напр. с двойным `//`:

    alert((("site/section//33").split("/"))[2] ? "есть":"нет")

Comment: @Sergiks, лично у меня "двойной //" вызывает только недопонимание по поводу необходимости его использования на своём сайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод строки `split()` [всегда возвращает](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) массив строк. Конструкция `if( str[2])` переводит значение третьего элемента массива в тип Boolean, чтобы сравнить с `true`.

Вот [как переводятся в Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) некоторые *строки*:

```
'stroka' 
'1'
'true'
'false'
'0'
// получат значение true
```

И только пустая строка

```
''
// получит значение false
```

Т.о. можно не опасаться, что, например, адрес `"/catalog/cars/0"` в вашей проверке ошибочно решит, что `str[2]` отсутствует.

В случае, если элементов меньше, `str[2]` вернёт undefined, который при переводе в тип Boolean становится false. Тоже всё ок.

Ваш вариант вполне рабочий! ([тест](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/hLdhmemc/))